# Is the value of 'this' in switch statement in Typescript 1.6.2 and atom-typescript emited incorrectly?

Tags: typescript, atom-editor

I have some Typescript code that looks something like this:

```
class Test {
    private userId: string
    constructor() {
      this.userId = 'test'
    }
    test() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let sharing = 'private'
        console.log("before switch this.userId", this.userId);
        switch (sharing) {
          case "private":
            resolve(this.userId);
            break;
        }
      })
    }
}
```

If I edit it in [the Typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground) the following Javascript code is emitted as I expect:

```
var Test = (function () {
  function Test() {
    this.userId = 'test';
  }
  Test.prototype.test = function () {
    var _this = this;
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var sharing = 'private';
        console.log("before switch this.userId", _this.userId);
        switch (sharing) {
            case "private":
                resolve(_this.userId);
                break;
        }
    });
  };
  return Test;
})();
```

However, if I edit the same code in my installed Atom editor, what is emitted is:

```
var Test = (function () {
  function Test() {
    this.userId = 'test';
  }
  Test.prototype.test = function () {
    var _this = this;
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var sharing = 'private';
        console.log("before switch this.userId", _this.userId);
        switch (sharing) {
            case "private":
                resolve(this.userId); // This resolve is missing a _
                break;
        }
    });
  };
  return Test;
})();
```

The difference is in the resolve statement 12 lines down. What is being resolved is `this.userId` instead of `_this.userId`.

I am running a new installation with:

- Atom 1.1.0
- atom-typescript 7.8.0
- Ubuntu 15.10
- typescript 1.6.2 installed with npm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue in TypeScript that was fixed two days ago : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5637

Is fixed in atom-typescript just now https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/releases/tag/v7.10.0

Answer (score 0):

I ran a test with your code on Webstorm 11 with TS 1.6.2 emitting ES5 and commonjs modules: the emitted JS code is correct.

To compile I had to declare `Promise` :

```
declare class Promise {
     constructor(callback: (resolve:Function, reject:Function) => void);
}
```

So I doubt, the compiler is the culprit although I do not see why the atom-typescript plugin would influence the emitted code. Contact the developper (Basarat Ali Syed)?

How is `Promise` declared ?

Comment: thanks for the input. Declaring Promise removes the error, but doesn't affect the Javascript that is emitted. I know that Basarat hangs out here, so hopefully he will get to see this. I will change the title to indicate that the problem is only apparent in atom-typescript.

Comment: I have tested the code in VS Code and it is emitted correctly, so it does look to be Atom-specific